# How to remove this warning message in my web application console

Tags: html, css, warnings

My problem is every time i go visit the browser console in my web application i got this kind of warning. Does anyone know how to fix this?

warning massage:

```
    Calling CSSStyleSheet.insertRule() with one argument is deprecated.
 Please pass the index argument as well: insertRule(x, 0).
```

Comment: Yes, modify your code according to what the console says here :)

Answer (score 2):

Wherever in your code you are using insertRule(CSS), you also need to define a second argument, which is the position you want the new CSS rule to be inserted into the existing stylesheet. For example, 0 means at the top of the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anybody in the future, I was receiving this error due to a Chrome Extension, in my case Super Simple Highlighter. Once I disabled it the error was gone, I also tested it by enabling the extension again, and the error returned. Feels good to know it wasn't my code causing it.

I was able to determine this by inspecting element and clicking on the file the console was pointing to (stylesheet.js:188). Upon scrolling to the top of that file, it said: "This file is part of Super Simple Highlighter."